# Recovering a local deleted file

Tags: git

I'm in a local branch.  I've deleted a file.  It is waiting to be staged and marked "deleted."  I have not ran `git rm`, `git commit`, `git add`, or anything else.  How can I restore that file?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [git recover deleted file where no commit was made after the delete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11956710/git-recover-deleted-file-where-no-commit-was-made-after-the-delete)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple:

```
git checkout HEAD  <filename>
```

should do the trick

Answer (score 1):

```
git checkout [filename]
```

OR

```
git checkout * <-- if you want recover all files in commit
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer to use `git gui`, you can unstage the deleted file (clicking on the icon, thus moving it to the top part) and then use `Commit - Revert Changes` (CTRL+J) to get the file back.