# Git fetch and git pull didn't copy files from remote repo

Tags: git, github

I have local project for which i created remote github repo. I didn't often push my local changes to remote repo but sometimes doing it. Recently while i was working on local project i have deleted some files using

```
rm fileName
```

After deleting i want to restore them and easiest way i think about was retrieving deleted files from github repo
I have only one master  branch in my repo and i tried

```
git fetch
```

And console prompt me that all files up to date after checking files which i need i didnt find them. After it i tried

```
git pull
```

and also i got notification that all files up to date and files which i need didnt uploaded to my local repo. I thought that maybe those files which i need haven't in remote repo but after checking i found them there. What i am doing wrong ?? How i should retrieve nedeed files ??

Comment: Does `git status` show them as deleted? If so just do `git checkout master -- fileName`. This resets the file to how it was at last commit, no pulling needed as you have a local copy of the whole repo already.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git recover deleted file where no commit was made after the delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11956710/git-recover-deleted-file-where-no-commit-was-made-after-the-delete)

Comment: @17slim thank you man i found solution by provided link

Comment: @17slim if you will write your message like answer i will flag it as right solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of playing with `git checkout` ([too confusing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066202/6309)) or `git reset`, the proper command (with a recent Git version 2.23+) would be to use [`git restore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore).

`git restore`... restore files.

In your case, you want the version which was in the index restored to your working tree (assuming your file was already tracked):

```
git restore -s@ -SW -- yourFile
```

It will restore the file from the last commit, and update both working tree and index, completely restoring the file.